# Dynamically create a text box instead of a drop-down based on selected value of first drop-down list

Tags: jquery, html, textbox, drop-down-menu, dynamic-forms

I'm almost there in achieving out what I have set out to do, please see the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xPye/2/

The only thing I wish to change is, instead of creating a `tags` dropdown based on the first drop-down's selected value I wish to generate a text box instead.

The reason for this is that there are simply too many options for it to be a dropdown so I'm hoping to make it a textbox and then hopefully add some auto-complete functionality to it once it is working.

An example of some `tags` that I would like to generate a textbox for rather than a drop-down would be all of the escherproperties - e.g. escherpropertyname, escherpropertynumber etc.

Any help and suggestions are much appreciated.

Regards,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following: 
1st - add a unique ID tag to each  tag heading and  textbox tag headings...this way you can easily reference the exact  or  tags you want.

2nd - use the .change() jquery function like so

```
$("select#dropbox1").change(function(){
  switch($(this).val()){
     case 'escherpropertyname': case 'escherpropertynumber': 
           $("select#dropbox2, $select#dropbox3, $select#dropbox4").css({display:'none'});
           $("input#textbox1, input#textbox2").css({display:'block'});
     break;
   };
});
```